# How to save reorder of rows in table view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am able to reorder the rows in tableview and navigate through app and my selection remains intact but when I restart the simulator the reorder is gone. Below is my code. How do I fix this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cityLabel: String = cityName[sourceIndexPath.row]
    cityName.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
    cityName.insert(goalToMoveLabel, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing came to my mind when I read your question is to save the data sources either in a database (Realm or CoreData or MySQLite or whatnot). You can also save your data sources in User Defaults.

Make sure when re-ordering the views/data, you are re-ordering your data source as well.

Then inside **viewDidLoad**, fetch the data sources, in your case, it's **cityName**.

After that, call `self.tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: :) I'm glad it helped. Do you mind selecting an answer?